# Persist keys through an FTP server

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm running a website and I've recently saw how persist keys will prevent my users from being logged out randomly while going through my site.  I looked up ways of persisting keys, but all I found was to do it through a file, or through a paid service.  This site is just a passion project, so I don't want to pay for something like this, though I also want people to say logged in.  Is there a way to have the keys be saved on a FTP server?